# Best Powershell verb to indicate Validation?

Tags: powershell, naming-conventions

I  often have a method that validates a particular value. In PowerShell, the convention is to use a verb within the [`Get-Verb`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-verb) list, but I am puzzled on which one would be best for this usage.

Alternatively, if my design  architecture should change to avoid validation through a method in some other manner I would welcome suggestions along that line too.

Verbs that are roughly related are: Ensure, Compare, Edit, Convert, Initialize, Update, Assert, Confirm, Measure, Resolve, Test, Write, Grant, Use.

Comment: What's the intended usage of your validation command? What's the workflow around it?

Comment: I'd go with 'Test', since that what a validation essentially is.

Comment: **Related:** Discussion on TechNet: 2012-05-02: [test vs confirm, which verb to choose?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0d9800f4-6a44-43e3-9cc4-eb739d729a52/test-vs-confirm-which-verb-to-choose)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Use "Test"

The appropriate verb for validating a value is `Test`. Quoting from the [Approved Verbs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands#diagnostic-verbs) list (section *Diagnostic Verbs*):

```
Verb (alias)   Action                       Synonyms to avoid
...            ...                          ...
Test (t)       Verifies the operation or    Diagnose, Analyze,
               consistency of a resource.   Salvage, Verify
```